# search and replace but only if between two markers php regex

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to replace the `<br>` tags with a space in a string containing html, but only if the tag is within a `<div class="nobr">` ..... `</div>` sequence. I presume the best way is to use preg_replace but I'm having difficulty finding the regex expression to use for the pattern... (there will be multiple line break tags and more than one "nobr" div)

e.g Simple example - From this:

keep this`<br>`line break`<div class="nobr">` but replace this linebreak`<br>`with a space`</div>`

To become:

keep this`<br>`line break`<div class="nobr">` but replace this linebreak with a space`</div>`

Comment: If you just want to not show the line break in browser, you can also replace it by space with CSS. See here: https://timonweb.com/css/how-replace-line-break-tags-br-spaces-css/

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915746/user1915746 just what I wanted!!

Answer (score 1):

You could first match the `nobr` elements and use a callback function with [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to replace the `<br>`.

```
$pattern = '/<div class="nobr">(.*?)<\/div>/s';
// This regex pattern will match any string that starts with 
// "<div class="nobr">" and ends with "</div>", and capture 
// all characters in between, including line breaks (using the "s" flag).

$string = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {
  return str_replace('<br>', ' ', $matches[0]);
  // The preg_replace_callback function will replace all 
  // "<br>" tags with spaces within each matched "nobr" div.
}, $string);
```

This would only work if you don't have nested divs, since the closing tag would match the nested div closing tag. If that's the case you need to use a [DOM parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nobr_divs = $xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' nobr ')]");

foreach ($nobr_divs as $nobr_div) {
    $br_tags = $nobr_div->getElementsByTagName('br');
    foreach ($br_tags as $br_tag) {
        $text = $doc->createTextNode(' ');
        $nobr_div->replaceChild($text, $br_tag);
    }
}

$new_html = $doc->saveHTML();
echo $new_html;
```

Comment: Note that this does not take in consideration for any other <div> elements within the nobr one, so the replacement can end early

Comment: @Randommm correct but if that's the case he would have to dom parse it. Will update the answer.